# Lotus-1-2-3 (wk1) file parsing guidelines

Tags: javascript, php, excel, lotus

I'm trying to make a little converter from wk1 (lotus-1-2-3) files to excel for a friend. The files have only simple data, no functions or anything really complicated.

I couldn't find anything related to guidelines to parse or documentation of wk1 file structure. I already tried going through libreoffice code but my C++ is very rusty (academic level, 6 years ago).

I usually code in PHP and JavaScript, and I didn't find anything related to this for these languages.

I believe I read somewhere that Lotus-1-2-3 is abandonware now, so I don't think is "illegal" or anything.

Is there any information available about this? What would be the best approach to "decoding" the data (other than that just give up)?

Thanks

Comment: `Lotus-1-2-3 is abandonware` no truer words have ever been said.

Comment: Indeed, but relevant enough for LibreOffice and gnumeric still reading these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me there is no reason to re-invent the wheel...

There is a free software that can convert these files.
It is even available as portable app AND it has a command- line parameter to convert between formats:
`soffice --headless --convert-to <TargetFileExtension>:<NameOfFilter> file_to_convert.xxx`

So if you really need an "own" program: package it with the portable version of libreoffice and make a nice interface to select the source and target file and run the command line...

Comment: I am trying to parse multiple files, clean the column headers and combine all of the data in one "excel" file (maybe xls or csv, not sure). But I guess your approach might be the better and definitely the most painless of the solutions.

Comment: You don't happen to know which filter should I use, do you? ask.libreoffice.org is down and I don't find the documentation for the "--infilter" parameter anywhere...

Comment: Nevermind, found it. It still doesn't work, but that's another thing.